# how to shutdown-restart-hibernate-stand by-log off computer using Process.Start()?

Tags: c#, process, cmd, shutdown

Im making a client-server application so i need to shutdown the remote pc **Silently** .. i've read about shutdown arguments in Commands Prompt shutdown/? .. but i still don't know  the right arguments to do the commands below.

shutdown

restart

hibernate

stand by

log off

lock (switch user)

so how do i do those commands locally without (**/m**) ?

```
void ShutDown(string cmd)
{
    Process.Start("shutdown", cmd);
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried shutdown ?/ in command shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

> To ShutDown : **shutdown -s**
>
> To Restart  : **shutdown -r**
>
> To Logoff : **shutdown -l**
>
> To Hibernate :**%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe PowrProf.dll,SetSuspendState**
>
> To Lock : **Rundll32.exe User32.dll,LockWorkStation**
>
> To Sleep : **rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0**

Note:While using cmd for Sleep Need to off Hibernation else sys will be hibernated.

Comment: what about sleep & lock and does this close all application silently ??

Comment: Hi @MurHafSoz when i use it from cmd Prompt it does the job silently i guess it does the same when you use in your Application also.

Comment: as you know it's difficult to try it on the local PC and check if it does work silently .. sometimes your PC shutdowns with a close application confirm dialog and sometimes it closes silently .. and because i read that -p (Turn off the local computer with no time-out or warning) and -f(Force running application to close without forewarning users) .. but i couldn't understand which's the right one for me ..